# Updating the app’s version number in flutter

Tags: flutter, version-numbering

I'm trying to deploy the flutter app, and now I'm trying to update the app's version number. Currently, it is "version: 1.0.0+2" but I just go with 1.0.0+3 for this time?

Comment: You can change the app version in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increment both values. So after `version: 1.0.0+2` it may be `version: 1.0.1+3` or anything else. Information about updating the version number in Flutter can you find on [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#updating-the-apps-version-number).